# How to check if expression will have a value after evaluating

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Let's say I have a following template:

```
"foo['x'] = '{{ myVar }}';"
```

Is there an angular way of checking if evaluating this against my current scope will give myVar some value ? I've got an array of such small templates and I only want to include them in the document when values are truthy. I was hoping either $interpolate, $parse or $eval might come in handy here. I know for sure that $interpolate is useless. What about the other two ? Maybe it's at least possible to get the name of the assigned value/expression ?

### EDIT

I wasn't specific enough. What I was trying to achieve, was checking in advance if for example template `'{{ myVar }}'` evaluated against the current scope will return an empty string or value of the scope variable (if it exists). The case was really specific - when traversing an array of short templates I wanted to know if a template will return as an empty string or not, and only include it in my final html if it doesn't.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? Do you mean you want to know the value of myVar in advance of actually parsing it? Or do you mean you want to parse the expression `{{myVar}}` and see if it has a value or not?

Comment: Can you create a plunk/fiddle of how you want to use this template? 
If you do the in a template, `foo.x` would en up with the string `'{{ myVar }}'`. I can't imagine what you want to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve, but to if you want to check if myVar is truthy in current scope, you can:

```
{{myVar ? "aw yiss" : "nope"}}
```

Evaluates to "aw yiss" if myVar is truthy and "nope" otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a modified $interpolate provider but maybe someone knows a shorter solution :

```
app.provider('customInterpolateProvider', [

  function $InterpolateProvider() {

    var startSymbol = '{{';
    var endSymbol = '}}';

    this.startSymbol = function(value){
      if (value) {
        startSymbol = value;
        return this;
      } else {
        return startSymbol;
      }
    };

    this.endSymbol = function(value){
      if (value) {
        endSymbol = value;
        return this;
      } else {
        return endSymbol;
      }
    };

    this.$get = ['$parse', '$sce', function($parse, $sce) {
      var startSymbolLength = startSymbol.length,
          endSymbolLength = endSymbol.length;

      function $interpolate(text, mustHaveExpression, trustedContext, allOrNothing) {
        allOrNothing = !!allOrNothing;
        var startIndex,
            endIndex,
            index = 0,
            expressions = [],
            parseFns = [],
            textLength = text.length,
            exp;

        var getValue = function (value) {
          return trustedContext ?
            $sce.getTrusted(trustedContext, value) :
            $sce.valueOf(value);
        };

        var stringify = function (value) {
          if (value == null) {
            return '';
          }
          switch (typeof value) {
            case 'string':
              break;
            case 'number': 
              value = '' + value;
              break;
            default: 
              value = angular.toJson(value);
          }

          return value;
        };

        var parseStringifyInterceptor = function(value) {
          try {
            return stringify(getValue(value));
          } catch(err) {
            console.err(err.toString());
          }
        };

        while(index < textLength) {
          if ( ((startIndex = text.indexOf(startSymbol, index)) !== -1) &&
               ((endIndex = text.indexOf(endSymbol, startIndex + startSymbolLength)) !== -1) ) {
            exp = text.substring(startIndex + startSymbolLength, endIndex);
            expressions.push(exp);
            parseFns.push($parse(exp, parseStringifyInterceptor));
            index = endIndex + endSymbolLength;
          } else {
            break;
          }
        }

        if (!expressions.length && !text.contains(startSymbol) && !text.contains(endSymbol)) {
          expressions.push(text);
        }

        if (!mustHaveExpression) {
          var compute = function(values) {
            for(var i = 0, ii = expressions.length; i < ii; i++) {
              if (allOrNothing && angular.isUndefined(values[i])) {
                return;
              }
              expressions[i] = values[i];
            }
            return expressions.join('');
          };

          return angular.extend(function interpolationFn(context) {
              var i = 0;
              var ii = expressions.length;
              var values = new Array(ii);

              try {
                if (ii && !parseFns.length) {
                  return expressions[0];
                } else {
                  for (; i < ii; i++) {
                    values[i] = parseFns[i](context);
                  }
                  return compute(values);
                }
              } catch(err) {
                console.err(err.toString());
              }

            }, {
            exp: text,
            expressions: expressions,
            $$watchDelegate: function (scope, listener, objectEquality) {
              var lastValue;
              return scope.$watchGroup(parseFns, function interpolateFnWatcher(values, oldValues) {
                var currValue = compute(values);
                if (angular.isFunction(listener)) {
                  listener.call(this, currValue, values !== oldValues ? lastValue : currValue, scope);
                }
                lastValue = currValue;
              }, objectEquality);
            }
          });
        }
      }

      return $interpolate;
    }];
  }
]);
```

Lines below were added because in some cases I have a predefined text in my short template and I always want to render it :

```
        if (!expressions.length && !text.contains(startSymbol) && !text.contains(endSymbol)) {
          expressions.push(text);
        }

                if (ii && !parseFns.length) {
                  return expressions[0];
                } else {
```